# Image not uploading in the folder of file manager codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

The image name is getting saved in the database but the image is not getting saved in the file manager, is there any permission problem in the file manager of cpanel or coding issue?

Controller

```
function addprofilepicture()
{
    $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
    $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
    $config['upload_path']          = './assets/Images/profilepictures';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    } else {
        $image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $this->m_user->update_pic($image);
    }
}
```

Model

```
public function update_pic ($image){
    if($this->session->userdata("user_id"))//If already logged in
    {
        $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
        $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
        $data = array('profile_pic' => $image,);

        $this->db->where('user_id', $userID);
        return $this->db->update('users', $data);
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('user/addprofilepicture'); ?>   
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" required>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" />

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: is it showing any error? if not, you should have 777 permission to profilepictures folder. Also you need to set permission of your parent folder and file which has uploading script.

Comment: Are you on a shared server? does it work on your localhost ? do you have at least 755 permission on the folder you want to upload to?

Answer (score 0):

Better use full path, that is if your assets is in the root directory (where the main index.php is)

`./` signifies current directory where upload is being executed

```
$config['upload_path']          = FCPATH.'assets/Images/profilepictures';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
function addprofilepicture()  {
   $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
   $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
   $config['upload_path'] = './assets/Images/profilepictures/';
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';       
   $this->upload->initialize($config);
   $this->load->library('upload', $config);
   if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());    
    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    } else {
    $image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $this->m_user->update_pic($image);
       }
      }
```

Comment: It Worked, Thanks

Comment: Can you consider this as answered?